# If $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable at $c$, then $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> If $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable at $c$, then $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $c$.

Here is my attempt:

Assume that $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable at $c$. Then $\mathbf{f}'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathbf{f}(c+h)-\mathbf{f}(c)}{h}$ is finite. Then $\mathbf{f}(x)-\mathbf{f}(c) = \frac{\mathbf{f}(x)-\mathbf{f}(c)}{x-c}(x-c)=\mathbf{f}'(c)(x-c)$. Then as $x\to c$, $\mathbf{f}(x)-\mathbf{f}(c)\to 0$, which proves that $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $c$.

Is this attempt okay? Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Your definition of the derivative is not correct. Remember, $f(x)$ is a vector

Comment: http://math.colorado.edu/~nita/Differentiability2.pdf

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan The definition of derivative is fine. The PDF you linked defines the derivative of functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, which is more complicated in general but reduces to this definition when $n = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct except for the following false claim:

> $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} (x-c) = f'(c)(x-c)$

This is only true in the limit!

Also, you should adjust your argument so that the limit you assume converges (currently $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$) is also the limit you use convergence of (currently $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$).

Comment: Oops! I totally realize my silly mistake. Thanks for the heads up on both things. :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you justify replacing the difference quotient with the derivative $ \mathbf {f}'(c)?$

$$\mathbf{f}(x)-\mathbf{f}(c) = \frac{\mathbf{f}(x)-\mathbf{f}(c)}{x-c}(x-c)=\mathbf{f}'(c)(x-c)$$